# Conditional Keyframes are not working while other properties are working fine. Ex. animation is not working, whereas font-size is working fine

Tags: emotion

The animation-name property is not working.

If I put the line **animation-name: ${bounce}** outside the condition, it works fine.

The property font-size works fine, whereas animation-name doesnt work.
Just wanted to add multiple animations based on conditions. This is just a sample code of the base error that is occuring. Is this a bug of emotion or I have made a mistake.

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { keyframes } from '@emotion/core'

const bounce = keyframes`
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
`;
const SomeDiv = styled.div`
  ${({showAnimation}) => "font-size: 20px;animation-name: ${bounce};"}
  color: blue;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
`;

render(
  <SomeDiv showAnimation={'yup'}>
    some bouncing text!
  </SomeDiv>
)
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error. `${ ... }` only works within backtick, you're using them inside regular quotes.

Comment: Its fine. No syntax Error is there. If syntax error would be there, font-size property wouldnt be working.

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes in Emotion should be either used in root template literal like this:

```js
const someDiv = styled.div`
   animation: ${bounce};
`
```

or if you want to put it inside another template literal, you should wrap it with css:

```js
const someDiv = styled.div`
   animation: ${css`${bounce}`};
`
```

the second syntax is useful when you want to set animation conditionally based on props for example:

```js
const someDiv = styled.div`
   animation: ${({ isBounce }) => isBounce ? css`${bounce} 200ms` : css`${someOtherAnimation} 400ms`};
`
```